# How to add a button at Page tab ribbon at publishing page?

Tags: ribbon, xml

Can you please help me in order to add a button at Page tab in publishing page. I am able to add the button in the documents library but I am not able to add the button at Page tab.

Here is the XML which I am using for the same:

```
<CommandUIExtension>
  <CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Page.Manage.Controls._children">
      <Button Id="NewUIRibbonControl.EnableRating"
              Alt="EnableRating"
              Sequence="1981"
              Command="EnableRating"
              LabelText="Enable Rating"
              TemplateAlias="o1"/>
    </CommandUIDefinition>
  </CommandUIDefinitions>
  <CommandUIHandlers >
    <CommandUIHandler Command="EnableRating"
    CommandAction="javascript:alert('hi');"/>
  </CommandUIHandlers>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

And also how to call C# function from here. Instead of alert I want to call a C# function.

Please let me know what's wrong there.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `Location` property is wrong. Depending on your settings and page layout correct location for Page tab is `Ribbon.WikiPageTab` or `Ribbon.WebPartPage`. There is no tab defined as `Ribbon.Page` in `\14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\CMDUI.XML`

You can easily check id of any tab if you use IE with Developing Tools or FireFox with FireBug to explore ribbon markup.

Example of ribbon markup - search for id of ul tag (it is Ribbon.WikiPageTab):

```
<div unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-tabContainer ">
    <ul unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-tabBody" id="Ribbon.WikiPageTab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Ribbon.WikiPageTab-title">
    <li unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-group" id="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout">
        <span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-groupContainer">
```

Only possible solution to call C# function from ribbon is through postback. I think it would be difficult to apply this technique on publishing page. Here is article on MSDN blogs on how to do it inside webpart: [Implementing a post back button in a SharePoint 2010 Web Part with contextual ribbon](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2010/12/30/implementing-a-post-back-button-in-a-sharepoint-2010-web-part-with-contextual-ribbon.aspx)